# Swapping two images doesnt work correctly using relative layout

Tags: android, layout

This is the code for swapping based on finger movement. I am able to swap but the images are not replacing the positions. After swapping the swapped image has to take the new position and animation has to set again for that. For this code it is redirecting to the old position and taking animation effect second time.

```
if (imageendX > imagestartX && imageendY < imagestartY) {

        if (imageendX - imagestartX < 60) {

        } else {


            TranslateAnimation tr = new TranslateAnimation(0,

            90, 0, 0);
            tr.setDuration(1000);
            // tr.setFillAfter(true);
            // tr.setFillEnabled(true);

            TranslateAnimation tr2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, -90, 0, 0);
            tr2.setDuration(1000);
            // tr2.setFillAfter(true);
            // tr2.setFillEnabled(true);


            currentView.startAnimation(tr);
            RightView.startAnimation(tr2);

            tr.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            tr2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

        }


    } else if (imageendY < -10) {


        TranslateAnimation tr = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -90);
        tr.setDuration(1000);
        // tr.setFillAfter(true);

        TranslateAnimation tr2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,90);
        tr2.setDuration(1000);
        // tr2.setFillAfter(true);

        currentView.startAnimation(tr);
        TopView.startAnimation(tr2);

        tr2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pr = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) TopView
                        .getLayoutParams();
                // pr.topMargin += 90;
                pr.topMargin += 90;
                TopView.setLayoutParams(pr);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        tr.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pr = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) currentView
                        .getLayoutParams();
                // pr.topMargin += 90;
                pr.bottomMargin += 90;
                currentView.setLayoutParams(pr);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    } else if (imageendY > imagestartY && imageendX < imagestartX) {

        if (imageendY - imagestartY < 60) {

        } else {



            TranslateAnimation tr = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, RM);
            tr.setDuration(1000);
            // tr.setFillAfter(true);

            TranslateAnimation tr2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -RM);
            tr2.setDuration(1000);
            // tr2.setFillAfter(true);

            currentView.startAnimation(tr);
            BottomView.startAnimation(tr2);

            tr2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            tr.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
        }

    } else if (imagestartX >= imageendX) {
        if (imagestartX - imageendX < 90) {
        } else {
            System.out.println("right to left");
            TranslateAnimation tr = new TranslateAnimation(0, RM, 0, 0);
            tr.setDuration(1000);
            tr.setFillAfter(true);

            TranslateAnimation tr2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, -RM, 0, 0);
            tr2.setDuration(1000);
            tr2.setFillAfter(true);

            LeftView.startAnimation(tr);
            currentView.startAnimation(tr2);

            tr2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            tr.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });


        }
        // }
    }
```

Comment: Need to swap images left to right and top to bottom and in reverse tooo.. Help me struggling from so many days....

Comment: Please make some effort to re-format your code so people will read it..

Comment: imageendX, imagestartX are the values when user touches the image and imageendY, imagestartY are the values when user releases the finger. current view is the image which user touches and left,right,top and bottom are respective to currentview. Based on the logic i written the images are swapping but again when i applied animation it is redirecting to old position and taking the animation effect. so now the imageview is getting empty...

Comment: Hi Amulya, did u get my question now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) the views will be in Original Position after the animation, So according to your requirement use [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) the views will be in Animated positons after the animation but the only downside is Property Animation supports from API 11

No Problem...Use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) to overcome that Problem..

**Sample Code with two image views**

Animation between imageOne and imageTwo

```
ObjectAnimator imageOneAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    imageOne, "X", imageOne.getX(), imageTwo.getX());
ObjectAnimator imageTwoAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    imageTwo, "X", imageTwo.getX(), imageOne.getX());
imageOneAnimator.setDuration(1000);
imageTwoAnimator.setDuration(1000);
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(imageOneAnimator, imageTwoAnimator);
set.start();
```

Animation between imageThree and imageOne

```
ObjectAnimator imageOneYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    imageOne, "Y", imageOne.getY(), imageThree.getY());
ObjectAnimator imageThreeYAnimator =      ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    imageThree, "Y", imageThree.getY(), imageOne.getY());
imageOneYAnimator.setDuration(1000);
imageThreeYAnimator.setDuration(1000);
AnimatorSet setY = new AnimatorSet();
setY.setStartDelay(1000);
setY.playTogether(imageOneYAnimator, imageThreeYAnimator);
setY.start();
```

You can start the animation in your touch listener according to your calculations

Comment: Hi seerm thanks for the interest for giving reply.. if u dnt mind can i have some example as i am new to android i am unable to find exact one.. please help me.. thanks...

Comment: Here you can find difference between the Translate Animation(View) and Object Animation(Property) http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/objectanimator-animation-in-honeycomb.html

Comment: Dude it is working fine..but when i apply animation again it is going back to original place and coming.. any solution...how to set that image to next image view there?

Comment: again it needs to take that particular positions animation..help me please

Comment: superb dude..but after imageone goes to imagetwo the imageone needs to set as second position then only i can animate with next animation, but it is setting as imageone only if i again applying animation for imageone again one and two are interchanging. but i need after animation i need to interchange with third one with the imageone..ur ans is nice.. but i need this one ..please help me in this issue dude.. im strugling from past 4,5 days..

Comment: We can, in ObjectAnimator change the arguement **X** to **Y** ,thats it :) and change **imageXxx.getX()** to **imageXxx.getY()**

Comment: Y you need to change the imageOne to imageTwo...Do this 1:Animate imageOne and imageTwo 2:Animate imageTwo and imageThree :)

Comment: if i do like that, means if i animated with two and three the imagetwo now which is in first position is animating with imageone again but in reverse direction yar.. im not getting two with the three...

Comment: Check the edited one..Sorry if i misunderstood the requirement,you are asking..If m right please accept the answer..It would helpful to others:)

Comment: surely dude..but one thing i need to clarify u with my requirement.. there is no imageone,imagetwo,tmagethree like that, in the on touch i have mentioned there as currentview, rightview,leftview,bottomview,topview.... so we need to write common logic for current view and right view for animating left to right..

Comment: Actually i was unable to understand your actual requirement..If there was an screenshot..then i can give the solution...m sorry:(

Comment: dude it is telling u need to have 10 reputations i am sending the link in that sliding images puzzle is there like that i need... if user swaps first image to second they both should replace the positions and again from second to third like that any where he can swap images in four directions(left - right, right - left, top - bottom, bottom - top)... see this link..https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.standardworks.tiles&hl=en

Comment: Gotcha:) but i cant explain you complete logic etc., i can just give suggestions..hope you understand..Happy Coding..:)

Comment: ya i just need, when image swapped just change the position too that all i need remaining code is done yar...